# Display name of Content Type instead of node Title in Views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have multiple different content types: *Part A*, *Part B*, *Part C*, etc.

What I need, is to display "Part A" in Views, instead of the title of the content. I also need to link to the content.

Is there an easy way to do this? It seems like such a simple thing, but I've found nothing on Google.

I'm thinking of using the Automatic Node Titles module to replace the title with "Part A (username - date)", so is this the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Go to your view. Add field >> Content: Type

[image]

Then in the field settings, check 'Link this field to the original piece of content'

[image]

That's it. You will find content type in each row. and if you click on it goes to node content page.